# Session Management for different folders

Tags: php, session

I am working on an application which contains two different portals (admin and members).
`http://localhost/app/` is used for the members login and `http://localhost/app/admin` is used for admin's login.

When I log in into members and admins portal both works fine but if I logout from one portal another portal logged out automatically.

I checked that the session file created in `/tmp/` directory stores the sessions information for both the portals in a single file which causes the above problem. The work around I think is to save the session information of both portals in different directories. I searched a lot for this but didn't get any resolution :(

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the different names for sessions by using session_name("session name for diff folders") before starting session_start() on every page where you want session and use different $_SESSION['admin_folder'] and $_SESSION['diff_folder'] var to set when you login to different directories and check if that is set then only can access that folder.

Comment: Great!! I am done with this and it works fine. Earlier I use the same but after the session_start().
Anyways thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy session elements individually instead of just calling `session_destroy();`.

For example, use `$_SESSION['logged_a']` for the admin and `$_SESSION['logged_u']` for the user.

And then, depending on where you logout from, do `unset($_SESSION['logged_a'])` or `unset($_SESSION['logged_u'])`

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions work on a per domain basis as they use cookies. If you want to have separate login systems for each directory your application will have to deal with that. A working approach would be to store the session id in a database along with a reference to which portals the session is logged in to. When a user logs out of one portal, rather than destroying the session, delete the record showing that the session is logged into that portal.